# Is this set $S = \{3, 3+1, 3+1+4, 3+1+4+5, 3+1+4+5+9,...\}$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Take any irrational number.
For example, $\pi$.

$$\pi = 3.14159\ldots$$

Define a set as follows $S = \{3, 3+1, 3+1+4, 3+1+4+5, 3+1+4+5+9,...\}$
Is $S$ countable or uncountable?

Comment: Countable, since you can count the digits.

Comment: Since your set is a subset of $\mathbb N$, it is obviously countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that set is a set of integers, so it is countable. (Remember that there are uncountably many *sets* of integers, even though there are only countably many *individual* integers; and each of the uncountably many sets of integers is itself countable.)

Answer (score 1):

It is countable, because you are enumerating the elements of the set by definition.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is a subset of integer.

Hence, $S$ is countable.